# Android: on creating a new custom theme with styles.xml

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Here's the styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Using the style above, the home screen shows as follows in Galaxy Note II (The theme of the home activity is `AppTheme` here.

[image: Home Activity]

And for the survey making activity, the theme is set as `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"` at AndroidManifest.xml. And here's the screenshot of the survey making activity.

[image: Survey Making Activity]

I managed to make the menu always shown on the bottom of the screen, but I keep struggling with applying the theme colour (tones) here. How should I modify the style so that the theme of the survey making activity has the same tone as the home activity, as well as keeping the menu always shown on the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Isn't there a light variant of the `AppBarOverlay` theme you're using?